# Ignore base url in html for local url

Tags: javascript, html, radix

I have base tag in my html page, and there is links that actually references to this base url, but, when i want to put a url that not references to the base url- it's not working!!

the urls that not references to the base url is:
  imageUrl: "images/like.png",
  contentUrl: "controls/small-pie-chart.html"

this is the code:

```
<base  href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/right-to-left-support" >
<style>
    html {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.metroblack.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="k-rtl">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">




            <div id="tabstrip-images"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#tabstrip-images").kendoTabStrip({
                animation: {
                    open: {
                        effects: "fadeIn"
                    }
                },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataImageUrlField: "imageUrl",
                dataContentUrlField: "contentUrl",
                dataSource: [
                    {
                        text: "נתונים כלליים",
                        imageUrl: "images/like.png",
                        contentUrl: "controls/small-pie-chart.html"
                        },

                      {
                        text: "מוכנות ביצוע",
                            imageUrl: "images/like.png",
                        contentUrl: "controls/small-pie-chart.html"
                    }
                    ]

            }).data("kendoTabStrip").select(0);
        </script>
    </div>


</div>
<style>
        html,
        body{
           position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
              margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-width: 0;
        }
        #tabstrip-parent,
        #tabstrip {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-width: 0;            }
        .k-tabstrip .k-content {
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with "/" at end of base URL
`<base  href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/right-to-left-support/" >`